# Neo4j: Create an index on all labels

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

i try to create indexes on all of the labels in the DB

this is what i have:

```
CALL db.labels()
YIELD label
CREATE INDEX ON :label(objectID)
```

but this gives an error:

> Invalid input 'N': expected 'p/P' (line 3, column 15 (offset: 44))
>   "CREATE INDEX ON :label(webint_keys_objectID)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use variables for labels in match, create, or schema operations. You must use the actual label for these operations.

There is a way to add indexes with dynamic labels using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema) using `apoc.schema.assert()`, **but it will drop all indexes and constraints that aren't present in the assert() call**. This would require transforming the labels from db.labels() into keys of a map, however, so you'd need other APOC procedures for that operation.

Since indexes and constraints only need to be created once, it's usually better to do these manually.

But if you do need such a query, this should do the trick:

```
call db.labels() yield label
with label, ['objectID'] as indexProp
with collect(label) as labels, collect(indexProp) as indexProps
with apoc.map.fromLists(labels, indexProps) as indexMap
call apoc.schema.assert(indexMap,{}) yield label, key, unique, action
return label, key, unique, action
```

Comment: the DB is created periodically new. your solution works like a charm. thx

Comment: I should have mentioned, if you want these as unique constraints instead of indexes (given your property is 'objectID', this may make sense), use indexMap as the second parameter in the assert call, that's for constraints, and leave the first parameter an empty map.

Comment: To supplement my past answer, [an additional boolean parameter can be provided](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_2) on whether to drop existing constraints or not. Default is true (to conform with past functionality), but you can supply `false` when you want to use this to add to existing schema instead of replacing it.